# check if user has a permission

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm doing a music bot and I'm working on the stop command.
The command works well and everything is fine but I have a problem with the permissions.
The permissions for that command is MANAGE_CHANNELS or DJ role.
When running the command with the DJ role, everything works fine,
but when you run the command with MANAGE_CHANNELS, it returns that the user has no access.

```
var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === djrole);
if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS") && !message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === djrole)) {
    const missingPerms = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("A3F9D0")
        .setTitle(`${deny} Missing Permissions & Roles!`)
        .setDescription(`**__Required Permissions__**
         \`MANAGE_CHANNELS\`

         **__Required Roles__**
         \`${role.name}\``)
         .setFooter(`Command ran by ${message.author.username}`)
          message.reply(missingPerms)
            .then((m) => {
              m.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
            })
            .catch(console.error);
     return false;
}
```

Comment: I can't help but saying that you should probably use `roles.cache.has(djrole)` instead of `roles.cache.find(role => role.id === djrole)`, line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this example worked:

```
var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === djrole);
if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS") && 
!message.member.roles.cache.has(role)) {
const missingPerms = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("A3F9D0")
    .setTitle(`${deny} Missing Permissions & Roles!`)
    .setDescription(`**__Required Permissions__**
     \`MANAGE_CHANNELS\`

     **__Required Roles__**
     \`${role.name}\``)
     .setFooter(`Command ran by ${message.author.username}`)
      message.reply(missingPerms)
        .then((m) => {
          m.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
        })
        .catch(console.error);
 return false;
```

I just edited your second line of code. It's a common way to check if a user has a specific role.